# How to read the voltage value at the touch point on the android device?

Tags: android, touchscreen

Now, I need to get the voltage value from the touchscreen when touched. I only can get the position I touch on by the android API. Does the android API provide the function?

Comment: not clear. You want to get voltage of the screen?

Comment: Capacitive touch screen have some voltage drop in the touch area. Thats how they identify the touch area. Please provide some more information

Comment: @Godwin You are right. There are some voltage drop when the screen touched. I want to get the voltage value. I know that using MotionEvent.getX() can get the touching position. How can I get the voltage value?